# Spring Data Jpa - How to perform roll back?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to perform rollback in Spring Data JPA for the following scenario?

```
Transactional
@Override
public Employee saveEmployee(EmployeeDto dto) {
    // check if EmployeeId and Department Id is present
    Employee employee = this.getByEmployeeId(dto);
    Department department = this.getByDepartmentId(dto);

    Employee employee = convertToEntity(dto, employee, department);
    employee.setEmployees(Arrays.asList(employee));
    department.setEmployees(Arrays.asList(employee));

    try {
        employee = employeeRepository.save(employee); //line-11
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "ConstraintViolationException", e.getCause());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new InternalServerException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, env.getProperty(IConst.ERROR_DB_EXCEPTION), ex);
    }

    EmployeeEmployeeDepartment r = new EmployeeEmployeeDepartment();
    r.setId(new EmployeeDepartmentPK());
    r.setEmployee(employee);
    r.setDepartment(department);
    r.setEmployee(employee);

    try {
        compositeRepository.save(r); //line-22
    }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "ConstraintViolationException", e.getCause());
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new InternalServerException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, env.getProperty(IConst.ERROR_DB_EXCEPTION), ex);
    }
    return employee;
}
```

How to roll back line-11 if line-22 fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Roll back transaction after exception in JPA + Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083020/roll-back-transaction-after-exception-in-jpa-spring)

Answer (score 2):

**1)** If `ResponseStatusException` and `InternalServerException` are both `RuntimeExceptions` then you do not need to do anything as Spring by default rolls back the entire transaction on any RTE.

**2)** Just keep in mind that invoking `save()` and eventually `persist()` on entityManager does not cause any physical update on the DB until the transaction commits. These methods simply register an entity in the Persistence Context.

Comment: In my case `ResponseStatusException ` extends `NestedRuntimeException` and `InternalServerException` extends `RuntimeException`. Do I need to really use transaction or not ?

Comment: You are performing save/update so you need a non-readonly transaction

Comment: You mean I should be using `@Transactional(readOnly = false)`

Comment: Very weird situation, when I used @Transactional, I see in debug mode, control is not coming to catch block its going somewhere and giving my own custom error and also giving long details of stack trace, why/.

Answer (score 2):

Use **"rollbackFor"**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
```

Multiple exception:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { ResponseStatusException.class, InternalServerException.class })
```

Comment: @M - By using this I am getting something weird exception, exception control not getting wrapped

Comment: Should I be using `@Transactional` from package `org.springframework.transaction.annotation` or package `javax.transaction`

Comment: My answer depends on Spring's package. So you can use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.